# Google datastore objectify save issue with map

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

`remove(0)` on a list having just one element in a `map` is making the `map` property disappear from an entity while saving to google datastore using objectify.

"`map`" is a property in the datastore entity.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map;
```

Saving after the following code causes the map property to disappear from datastore when the list corresponding to the key `"dress"` has just one element even if corresponding to other keys there are lists with any number of elements.

```
map.get("dress").remove(0)
```

Note: the issue does not happen when there is more than one element in the list.

Comment: You mean having an empty list in a map with other elements causes the whole list to be discarded? Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Yes. only while removing an element if the list becomes empty, then the whole map is discarded.

Comment: @Eric Actually I just noticed, even if you have just a list property in a entity and when you remove the last element in the list, the whole list is discarded. I would expect there to be an empty list.

Comment: Oh I had a mistake in my comment. Does an empty list cause the entire `map` to be discarded, or does it only cause that **entry** to be discarded? The latter would not surprise me, though I cannot find anything in the docs about it.

Comment: If removing an element from a list makes the list empty, then the map this list is part of is discarded.

In addition what I noticed was, if the list was a direct entry in the entity instead of being part of the map, then too the list entry is discarded when you do a remove of the last element in the list. I would expect there to be an empty list in this case.

I am guessing the above two are related?

Comment: Wanted to re-emphasize that I am using objectify.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying that the `map` still exists, it just lacks the empty list that you expected to be preserved. In that case, see my answer below.

Comment: No, the map does not exist at all.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, then. I'm back to thinking think is a bug. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was a bug in the way map was being saved in Objectify version 5.1.8 all the way upto 5.1.12. We upgraded to 5.1.13 and this works now.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the Java SDK is as follows (from [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Using_an_empty_list)):

> - Null properties are written as null to the data store
> - Empty collections are written as null to data store
> - A null is read as null from the data store
> - An empty collection is read as null.

You can change that so empty lists are preserved using

```
System.setProperty(DatastoreServiceConfig.DATASTORE_EMPTY_LIST_SUPPORT, Boolean.TRUE.toString())
```

Be sure to read the doc section listed above before turning that feature on; it lists several caveats to be aware of.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments with the question, the issue I am facing is that the map disappears.